# Asp Mvc What's Easiest way to do client validation without using DataAnnotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation

Folks,
   I'm doing an in-house proof of concept for ASP MVC 2.0 (I'm no expert on ASP or Web Technologies either).
I've a requirement for dynamic forms (form details - no of fields, field types, field Is Mandatory etc - loaded from a database at runtime), and can't see how to apply DataAnnotations in this instance.

What is the simplest way to have client side validation without using DataAnnotations, is it possible to somehow hook into (*something like*) the existing `ValidationMessage` and `ValidationMessageFor` extensions without using DataAnnotations?

Thanks
BW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the [jquery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) directly and define client side validation rules in javascript. Because those rules need to be dynamic you could use a HTML helper to generate them depending on the fields on the form or have another separate controller action that will emit this dynamic javascript and have a `<script>` tag point to this action.